# Odd SPARQL Behaviour

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am currently working on iterative expansion algorithm that will form the basis for a project. The algorithm is given a seed URI, based on which it creates a graph in memory, by expanding step-by-step, keeping track of already visited nodes and a frontier of unexplored territory. To create this expansion, I have created two SPARQL templates that I feed URIs from the frontier into. The two simplified expressions are:

```
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o}
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER(?s IN (<URI_1>, <URI_2>,... <URI_N>)) .
    FILTERS....
}
```

and

```
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o}
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER(?o IN (<URI_1>, <URI_2>,... <URI_N>)) .
    FILTERS...
}
```

The first expression gets all triple in which the frontier nodes are subjects, and the second expression gets all triples in which the frontier nodes are objects. It should also be noted that I add in several filters, which have been left out for simplicities sake.

When I execute these queries, there is a rather large difference in execution time between statement one and two. Statement one is executed 3-6x faster than statement two, even though the statements are largely the same.

Could someone provide a hint as to why there is such a large discrepancy between the two queries? And even better, how query two might be restructured in order to attain better performance?

Comment: You haven't told us which SPARQL egine or triple store you're using. A possible cause is that the store you're executing over indexes on subjects but not on objects. It could also be that the second query simply returns a lot more results. But it's impossible to tell without knowing more about your specific setup.

Comment: Also, a naive engine might actually do a filter for `FILTER ( ?s in ... )`, generating lots of triples first, and then filtering out results.  You could use `values ?s { ... }` instead, which should be equivalent, but might be more efficient with a naive engine.  It's worth trying anyhow.

Comment: Hello Joshua. I attempted a trail using VALUEs instead of filters. The results are:
Outbound avg time: 934ms
Inbound avg time: 4065ms

So it does not appear to make much of a difference. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Hello Jeen. I am currently running against a Virtuoso server, DBpedia more specifically. I assume, although I obviously don't know, that Virtuoso indexes on both objects and subjects.

Comment: I believe I have found a solution. Changing the SPARQL expression to a SELECT statement makes a radical difference:
Outbound avg time: 607
Inbound avg time: 634

I can only assume that CONSTRUCT in some, costly, way restructures the data before sending it.

Comment: @user2357906 How many triples are in each construct result?  Also, what format are you getting the results back in?  TTL and RDF/XML do support "pretty" formats that could take longer to write because properties and values for single subject can be grouped, but subjects and properties of a single object can't.  So constructing the graphs probably uses roughly the same amount of time, but writing and sending the output could take much longer.  How big is the actual response data you're getting back in each case?

Comment: E.g., the triples `s p1 o1. s p1 o2. s p2 o3` can be written `s p1 o1, o2 ; p2 o3 .`, but `s1 p1 o . s2 p1 o . s3 p2 o` can't be cleaned up in TTL and RDF/XML.   Using a format where each requires three lines (e.g., N-Triples) might make the difference go away.

Comment: Also, what set of URIs are you using where you get roughly the same number of triples back in each case?  All the ones I've tried so far tend to be "subject intensive".  I.e., when I provide them as subjects, I get more results back.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I am currently using Jena to retrieve data, so I cannot tell you which format the data returns in. I have been encountering issues with too long query strings, så my system simply chops up the array of URI strings into buckets of max 4000 characters. This seems to work fine, but it does mean that I get rather varied sizes of queries

Comment: I strongly advise that you test your queries through the [DBpedia SPARQL query form](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), and not just through Jena. I would not expect the same issues you report with long query strings, nor the extreme difference between `CONSTRUCT` and `SELECT` query execution times.  Whether my expectations play out or not, those tests should give you some clear paths to investigate going forward.

Comment: Questions specifically regarding [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com) (from my employer) are generally best raised on the [public OpenLink Discussion Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), or through a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Comment: @TallTed Thank you for the suggestion. I have implemented an algorithm that works around the issue, and provides pretty good retrieval time.

Comment: @user2357906 - Now it's time to post the answer to your question, and (in a few hours, when you get the little checkmark icon) to accept that answer.

Or delete the question.

Comment: @user2357906 How did you resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi @JoshuaTaylor - The short answer is that I switched to using SELECTs.

The long answer is that I built an algorithm that attempted to pack the frontier such that I would use the least amount of SPARQL calls in order to explore the frontier. If you want a more detailed explanation, I have a report here somewhere...